# Love2D keyboard.isDown key values?

Tags: keyboard, lua, love2d

Is there a list of key values somewhere? I might be completely derping out, but I haven't found a list. Can someone help?

Comment: You could write a simple script that would output the key values each time you press a key, then create a map based on the output.

Comment: Actually, there is [one](https://love2d.org/wiki/KeyConstant) on the wiki... :)